# How to insert data in two table on single click where 1st query id is used in another

Tags: c#, sql

**UPDATE**

```
protected void submit()
{
    int pptId = 0;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dt = new DataTable();
        string name = tbPPTName.Text;
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ppt_Master WHERE ppt_Name='@ppt_Name'";
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) // Means first name is already present
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "This ppt is already added!";
        }
        else if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblmsg.Visible = false;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ppt_Master(Userid,ppt_Name,ModuleId,Description,Priority,IsEnable,dt) OUTPUT INSERTED.pptId values('" + Session["trainer"] + "','" + tbPPTName.Text + "','" + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "','" + tbDescription.Text + "','" + lblPriority.Text + "','" + chkIsEnable.Checked + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppt_Name", tbPPTName.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", ddlModule.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());//
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbDescription.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsEnable", true);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                pptId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             }
            tbPPTName.Text = "";
            tbDescription.Text = "";
            tbPPTName.Focus();
            Logs.InsertLogs(Session["Role"].ToString() + ":" + Session["trainer"].ToString(), "CreatePPT.aspx.cs submit()", "Query Successfully Executed for submit()");
            lblmsg.Text = "PPT Created";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }            
    }

    #region content
    ViewState["pptId"] = pptId.ToString();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string path = "http://Userlogin.aspx?pptId=" + pptId.ToString();            
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into windowformsppt(ContentName,ContentPath,Contenturl,Enableurl,dt) values ('" + tbPPTName.Text.ToString() + "','c:\t.exe' ,'" + path + "','No'" + ",'" + DateTime.Now + "')";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentName", "Assessment " +tbPPTName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contentpath", "c:\t.exe");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contenturl", "http://fpcbt/Userlogin.aspx?pptId=" + pptId.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

How to solve this error? What I want is to collected the created `pptid` into a string and then pass that string into content url. How can I do that?

Comment: Different RDBMS have different ways to get back the identify values created by an insert statement.  Which RDBMS are *you* using?  MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, PosGreSQL, etc, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing that u r using SQL SERVER as back end

Try [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause i.e `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID`

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ppt_Master(Userid,ppt_Name,ModuleId,Description,Priority,IsEnable,dt) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID values('" + Session["trainer"] + "','" + tbPPTName.Text + "','" + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "','" + tbDescription.Text + "','" + lblPriority.Text + "','" + chkIsEnable.Checked + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

Then get this inserted id using [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int newId = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Assumes SQL-Sever; which should therefore be stated in the answer.

Comment: @NitinVarpe can you tell how exactly i use user code as my mind is not working now sry but i m totally lost because i use brain a lot

Comment: @Amitesh ExecuteScalar returns first column of first row of last query  which in ur case will be Id as we have returned OUTPUT INSERTED.ID from query

Comment: @Amitesh you need not even need to use OUTPUT INSERTED.ID so just using ExecuteScalar would do it

Comment: when i use cmd.commedtext and int newid both my data inserted twice in ppt_Master table

Comment: I think u r still using ExecuteNonQuery() remove it

Comment: i am telling you this error after removing ExecuteNonQuery() friend

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49049/discussion-between-amitesh-and-nitin-varpe)

Comment: Thanks @ Nitin its working now but tbPPTName is showing empty value for second table

Comment: you have written one line after first command execution i.e tbPPTName.Text = "";